# Show that the mapping $\overline{\text{tan}}:[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We look at the set $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and the standard topology as well as define: $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\,\cup\,\{-\infty,\infty\}$

Show that the mapping $\overline{\text{tan}}:[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a homeomorphism with

$\overline{\text{tan}}(x):=\begin{cases}
\text{tan}(x) & ,x\in]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[\\
\infty& ,x=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
-\infty &,x=-\frac{\pi}{2} 
\end{cases}$

A homeomorphism function is a continuous function between topological spaces that has a continuous inverse function.

On the set $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\,\cup\,\{-\infty,\infty\}$ a topology is defined as: A subset $U\subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is open if the following requirements are fulfilled:

(i) $\,$ $U \cap \mathbb{R}$ is open in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$

(ii) $\,$ If $\infty \in U$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $]r,\infty[ \subset U$.

(iii) $\,$ If $-\infty \in U$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $]-\infty,r[ \subset U$.

This is a exercise from an old analysis exam as I am currently learning for my upcoming test. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to start solving the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which topology are you assuming on $\overline{\Bbb R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: Show that the usual open intervals on $\Bbb R$ together with sets of the form $(r, \infty]$ and $(-\infty, r)$, form a basis for the topology on $\overline{\Bbb R}$.

Hint 2: Show that $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is Hausdorff.

Now, $\overline{\tan}$ is continuous because $\overline{\tan}^{-1}([-\infty, r))$ and $\overline{\tan}^{-1}((r, \infty])$ are open in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Also, $\overline{\tan}$ is bijective.

Continuous bijections from a compact space to a Hausdorff space are homeomorphisms.